# Ajax in Wp work only in index.php but not in footer,php and other pages

Tags: ajax, wordpress

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php") ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'action=my', // можно также передать в виде массива или объекта
        success: function( data ) {
            alert( data );
        }
    });
```

This code work only in index.php

Answer (score 0):

Inline usage of Ajax requests is not acceptable in WordPress.

Instead of it you need to use the code like this:

**Javascript**

```
var data = {
    'action' : 'my_action'
};

jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

});
```

**PHP**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_func'  );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action',  'my_action_func');

function my_action_func(){
    echo 'this is result';
    wp_die();
    return;
}
```

Notes: put JavaScript is code in .js file, `ajaxurl` should be defined before the   ajax request.